Convert character encoding in big database
We have big database (~1TB) and we need to update character encoding for all tables.
I am running following SQL:
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER DATABASE wallmob_etail CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
ALTER TABLE `table_1` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
ALTER TABLE `table_2` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
...
ALTER TABLE `table_212` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

It takes very long to process (like 40 tables in 3h).
Is there any faster way to execute these queries? Database can be fully locked, as we are using AWS Blue/Green deployments.

There is no faster way to do this. Changing the character set and/or collation must rebuild any indexes on string data, because the index order may change. The time it needs to do this is proportional to the size of the index.
To mitigate the inconvenience of locking, I would use an online schema change tool. I have used pt-online-schema-change. You may also consider gh-ost. Both of these are free and open source.
Using the online schema change tools, the change may actually take longer than using ALTER TABLE, but since it allows you to continue reading and writing the table while it works, this isn't as big a problem.
